# add redirection to directory and subdirectory

Tags: html

A have a multilingual website in English and Arabic. I add the redirection code in .htaccess but only English pages are redirected and my (sub directory ar) its not working.

I want to know how I can solve this issue.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arianamedicaretour.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.arianamedicaretour.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: *"... only English pages are redirected and my (sub directory ar) its not working"* - it's working when I try it. So we might do something different here. Unfortunately it is not clear what since you don't describe what exactly you are trying and what you are observing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to redirect entire my website in multilingual html website](https://serverfault.com/questions/1155827/how-to-redirect-entire-my-website-in-multilingual-html-website)