# how to redirect entire my website in multilingual html website

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect, html, folder-redirection, html5

i have a multilingual website, Arabic and English, my English pages its in rood directory and Arabic pages its in folder name ar; but i got my auditing report that; Search engines see

- `www.arianamedicaretour.com/ar/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9-.html` and
- `arianamedicaretour.com/ar/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A6%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A%D8%A9-.html`

as two different websites with the same content. This causes them to
see a lot of duplicate content, which they don't like.

I created a redirect code in `.htaccess` only English pages are redirecting but the redirect code its not reflecting to my subdirectory.

```
Redirecting code:
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www to www with HTTPS for the entire site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^arianamedicaretour\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.arianamedicaretour.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Ensure all requests are served over HTTPS
# This rule checks if HTTPS is not on, and it will redirect all requests to HTTPS without specifying the domain again
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

can you please check what is the issue on this code and why not reflecting in subdirectory?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with the code as posted, it should redirect as required. Do you have any other directives in this .htaccess file? Do you have another .htaccess file in the `/ar` subdirectory? And if so, what does this 2nd .htaccess file contain?

Answer (score 1):

In general SEO issues are more on topic on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

The behaviour of directives `.htaccess` can be modified by other  `.htaccess` files in parent and/or sub-directories and suffer from a performance penalty.

The .htaccess directives look OK, but in general [only use `.htaccess` files when you don't have access to the main apache configuration files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html#when) and the VirtualHost definition.

Especially [the trivial use-case that you have, a simple redirect to HTTPS, should be done with a `Redirect` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   
   ServerName www.arianamedicaretour.com
   ServerAlias arianamedicaretour.com
   Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.arianamedicaretour.com/"

</VirtualHost >
<VirtualHost *:443>
   
   ServerName arianamedicaretour.com
   ## TLS settings and such 
   Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.arianamedicaretour.com/"

</VirtualHost >
<VirtualHost *:443>
   

    ServerName www.arianamedicaretour.com
    ## TLS settings and such 
    ## DocumentRoot and other directives that relate to the content of the site

</VirtualHost >
```

Comment: when i add the code i got a error in all my pages as:

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@arianamedicaretour.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. kindly advice.

Comment: You don’t add that to an .htaccess file though, but rather to the main httpd.conf where your virtual host is defined